# How to combine reading a file line by line and iterating over each character in each line?

Tags: rust

I started from this code, which just reads every line in a file, and which works well:

```
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let file = File::open("chry.fa").expect("cannot open file");
    let file = BufReader::new(file);
    for line in file.lines() {
        print!("{}", line.unwrap());
    }
}
```

... but then I tried to also loop over each character in each line, something like this:

```
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let file = File::open("chry.fa").expect("cannot open file");
    let file = BufReader::new(file);
    for line in file.lines() {
        for c in line.chars() {
            print!("{}", c.unwrap());
        }
    }
}
```

... but it turns out that this innermost for loop is not correct. I get the following error message:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `chars` found for type `std::result::Result<std::string::String, std::io::Error>` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:8:23
  |
8 |         for c in line.chars() {
  |                       ^^^^^
```

Comment: Note the difference between your handling of `line`: in the first snippet you call `line.unwrap()` whereas in the second you directly attempt to call `line.chars()` without first unwrapping; something is missing :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to handle the potential error that could arise from each IO operation, represented by an `io::Result` which can contain either the requested data or an error. There are different ways to handle errors.

One way is to just ignore them and read whatever data we can get.

The code shows how this can be done:

```
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let file = File::open("chry.fa").expect("cannot open file");
    let file = BufReader::new(file);
    for line in file.lines().filter_map(|result| result.ok()) {
        for c in line.chars() {
            print!("{}", c);
        }
    }
}
```

The key points: `file.lines()` is an iterator that yields `io::Result`. In the `filter_map`, we convert the `io::Result` into an `Option` and filter any occurrences of `None`. We're then left with just plain lines (i.e. strings).

Comment: Awesome with the explanation of IoResult too, thanks!